# Facebook Unity 5.0.3 Login Failed

Tags: facebook, authentication, unity-game-engine, facebook-login, facebook-unity-sdk

Hi I'm integrating Facebook with my Unity3d game

The problem is that, it seems like players can't login to facebook properly. There are error logs here

> OverflowException: Value is greater than Char.MaxValue or less than
>   Char.MinValue System.Convert.ToChar (Int32 value)
>   Facebook.MiniJSON.Json+Parser.get_PeekChar ()
>   Facebook.MiniJSON.Json+Parser.EatWhitespace ()
>   Facebook.MiniJSON.Json+Parser.get_NextToken ()
>   Facebook.MiniJSON.Json+Parser.ParseValue ()
>   Facebook.MiniJSON.Json+Parser.Parse (System.String jsonString)
>   Facebook.MiniJSON.Json.Deserialize (System.String json)
>   Facebook.IOSFacebook.OnLogin (System.String msg)

I have a button that calls FB.login when pressed. After the player press it, the app redirect to Facebook app properly, and redirect back to my game without problem. But the login is not success and I can't get Player's Facebook info.

ps It's quite for me to get a proper log, because this scenario happens to my player's device. My test devices (iPhone4s and iPad4) are working very fine. I have no idea how to fix it

Thanks
Karnpot

Comment: Well we can't really answer your question, without the code. How you do you Initialize your FB class and how do you store and use the FB profile class.

Comment: check this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/change-log

Comment: Thanks for you help, but the question is too old I'm not paying attention to it anymore. Plus, the old code is already gone. Thanks again.